# "NDK version is UNKNOWN" after installation

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-ndk

I just installed the newest of Android Studio, and I opened my project and started to sync and this error showed up:

> NDK Resolution Outcome: Project settings: Gradle model version=5.4.1, NDK version is UNKNOWN

What's going wrong?

Comment: error "Gradle sync failed: C:\Users\TIK\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)" and NDK Resolution Outcome: Project settings: Gradle model version=5.4.1, NDK version is UNKNOWN

Answer (score 0):

After installed the newest of Android Studio Gradle model version=5.4.1 this contains all xml code in androidx so first try to refactor it by using

> Refactor->migrate to androidx

then try to sync it.

Comment: still showed this "Gradle sync failed: C:\Users\TIK\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)"

Comment: and this

NDK Resolution Outcome: Project settings: Gradle model version=5.4.1, NDK version is UNKNOWN

Comment: try to sync app with internet connection is there any missing file or dependancy then gridle automatically download it.